# 2048 Pythonic Merge Function

Tags: python, game, matrix

This post goes over how I updated my 2048 merge function code from spaghetti code to being somewhat more readable.

[Spaghetti Old Code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/103764/2048-merge-function)

I incorporated a few techniques from pretty much all of your suggestions! I realized there were **a lot** of logical mistakes and redundancy in my code, like why append 0's over and over again when it's not necessary at all, because in the end I back-track, account for missing numbers, and then append 0(s) in their place.

**Improvements in new code vs. old code**:

1. Use of list comprehensions
2. Use of Python's built-in truthiness
3. Minimal branches (fewer `if`(s), `else`(s), etc.)
4. Infusing new and useful methods like `extend` into my code
5. Improving the code style by enhancing readability
6. Removing redundandcy and flawed logic

---

```
def merge(nums):
    '''
    Takes a list as input
    returns merged pairs with
    non zero values shifted to the left.
    fancy interactive doc test below, no output means no problems.
    >>> merge([2, 0, 2, 4])
    [4, 4, 0, 0]
    >>> merge([0, 0, 2, 2])
    [4, 0, 0, 0]
    >>> merge([2, 2, 0, 0])
    [4, 0, 0, 0]
    >>> merge([2, 2, 2, 2, 2])
    [4, 4, 2, 0, 0]
    >>> merge([8, 16, 16, 8])
    [8, 32, 8, 0]
    '''
    slide = [num for num in nums if num]
    pairs = []
    for idx, num in enumerate(slide):
        if idx == len(slide)-1:
            pairs.append(num)
            break
        elif num == slide[idx+1]:
            pairs.append(num*2)
            slide[idx+1] = None
        else:
            pairs.append(num)  # Even if not pair you must append
    slide = [pair for pair in pairs if pair] 
    slide.extend([0] * (len(nums) - len(slide)))
    return slide

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

**Sidenote**: Pylint yells at me for using `i` instead of `idx`.

Comment: You could deal with pylint errors by making pylint configuration file. On of configuration is describing good names.

Answer (score 2):

I didn’t review or see your old code when it was posted, but this is noticeably improved. However, I can still make a few suggestions:

- `num` and `nums` are not great variable names. Characters are cheap; just write out the word `number` in full. I would also suggest giving `numbers` a slightly different/longer name to make it easier to read the line where you define `slide`.

  Likewise `pair`/`pairs` could be a little easier to read, I think.
- A few comments on the different branches to explain why you’re behaving in a particular way would be useful – to somebody unfamiliar with the rules of 2048, it might not be immediately obvious why it behaves the way it does.
- A description of the doctest doesn’t belong in the function docstring, it probably belongs in a comment on the main() function. If I import your function into another file and then inspect `merge.__doc__`, the mention of a doctest “below” could be confusing.
- Having “no output” mean success could be a problem, because there’s no way for me to distinguish between a success and the test not running. It should be totally clear whether your test passed, failed, or didn’t run. Anything else can hide problems.

Comment: A description of the doctest doesn’t belong in the function docstring, -> it does.  Having “no output” mean success could be a problem -> no, it is good common practice, run tests in verbose mode if it bothers you.